# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, protocol<>>' to 'Swift.AnyObject'

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift2

I am trying to cast my `[String : Any]` to a JSON Format before sending it to an API.

```
var orderRequestUserValues : [String : Any]   = [ "ClientID": "\(clientID)",
                                                       "UserName": "\(userName)",
                                                       "Password": "\(password)",
                                                       "ModuleID": "StockProcessing",
                                                       "FunctionID": "SetStockOrder",
                                                       "TransmissionFlags": 32,
                                                       "TransmissionMethod": 5


    ]

var requestParameters : [String : Any] = [  "ActivityType": 2,
                                            "ActivityReference1": "",
                                            "ActivityReference2": "",
                                            "Notes": "",
                                            "ProcessingUserUnique": 1
                                            ]

requestParameters.updateValue(usedObjectDictionaries, forKey: "ListofStockActivityData")


orderRequestUserValues.updateValue(requestParameters, forKey: "RequestParameters")
```

But because my method of casting expects a `AnyObject` I try and force cast it, but I receive an error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary>' to 'Swift.AnyObject'.

```
do{

   let newDict = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(orderRequestUserValues as! AnyObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)  // Inflicts an error

   let decoded = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(newDict, options: [])
```

Must I use another method of casting to JSON format, or what would be my best alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with Swift 2 and the problem you have is about `Any` not convertible to `AnyObject`. Down casting from `Any` to `AnyObject` is not possible. So declare your dictionary as `[String: AnyObject]` instead of `[String: Any]`.

```
var orderRequestUserValues : [String : AnyObject]   = [ "ClientID": "\(clientID)",
                                                   "UserName": "\(userName)",
                                                   "Password": "\(password)",
                                                   "ModuleID": "StockProcessing",
                                                   "FunctionID": "SetStockOrder",
                                                   "TransmissionFlags": 32,
                                                   "TransmissionMethod": 5]
```

Comment: Yes it is (: Just having some issues with the Api reading the JSON

Comment: @LenxvanZyl You can post another question on SO for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

`[String : Any]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<String, Any>`) is a struct, not an object. Thus, it cannot be cast to `AnyObject`.

However, `Dictionary` (explicitly) bridged to `NSDictionary` by casting:

```
 let newDict = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(orderRequestUserValues as NSDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
```

Comment: What would be my best alternative?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'Dictionary<_, _>' in coercion

Comment: Oops, i made a typo. I meant that to be `NSDictionary`. You could've picked up on it, based off the previous sentence :p

Comment: Firstly had to change [String : Any]  to [String : AnyObject]

Comment: Worked!!!!!!!  but with one warning as  "Conditional cast from '[String : AnyHashable]' to 'NSDictionary' always succeeds "                                               
    (p as? NSDictionary)!   where  p is  [String:AnyHashable]

Comment: @VinodSupnekar Then you can just use `as`. But in either case, you shouldn't do this anymore. You should use the Codable protocol for really easy JSON/PropertyList serialiization/deserialization https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Comment: @Alexander thank you for reply!  'as' worked for me.                                       As 'p' is Array of Dictionary , it is already Codable  , so what's your point to say here?

Comment: @VinodSupnekar I'm saying that `NSJSONSerialization` (and my answer) is obsolete, and that the new standardized way of encoding/decoding JSON is with the Codable protocol and friends

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, this way is working perfectly fine for me.

let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: newDictionaryResult!)